# Interval of definition for the solution $\ln|y|+y^2=\sin(x)+1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The problem is as follows:

We have the differential equation: $\frac{dy}{dx}= \frac{y cos(x)}{(1+2y^2)}=f(x,y),$ $y(0)=1$

Finding the maximum and minimum value of $\frac{y}{1+2y^2}$, show that $|f(x,y)|\leq \frac{1}{(2sqrt2)}$ and use this result to show that the interval of definition for the solution $\ln|y|+y^2=\sin(x)+1$ is $- 
\infty < x < \infty$

How do I show the last part?

Comment: How do I prove the last part?

Comment: Did you find the maximum and minimum?

Comment: Yes it is just $\frac{1}{2sqrt2}$